# exec method in java not able to execute command

Tags: java, command

I am trying to execute command using exec method

```
proc3=Runtime.getRuntime().exec("umount "+m);
```

Where m is variable having directory location like /mnt, /media
When i execute the command in command prompt it will work as expected, but with java exec method it's not working giving exit status 2.
What may be the reason ?

Comment: One of the reason for this behaviour is that all the environment variables are not available to the java runtime, as a test can you indentify the absolute path of umount and use it. If that works, the PATH is not available.

Comment: You can try calling a script that redirects the error to a file, ie write a shell script which has the command umount $1 > out.log 2> out.err. This way you might be able to catch the error and get an idea of the underlying OS error

Comment: the error is you are not root

Answer (score 1):

Try with [ProcessBuilder](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html) :

```
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("umount",p1,p2);
pb.start();
```

You can pass to ProcessBuilder's constructor as many arguments as you want .

PS : Don't forget to check your permission.

Comment: I got to know problem is permission . I must be root user to execute the command. But servlet will run as nobody user

Answer (score 0):

You have two option with you. 
1) To start your server/servlet using su(not an ideal option). 
2) Provide sudo access on umount to the user starting the servlet service, so that it can execute (might need a password). You might have to check this.

Steps to Identify the error:
Write a shell script which has the command umount $1 > out.log 2> out.err. This will log any OS error onto a file which enables further debug.

Comment: I solved this problem by creating small c++ program to execute the command and providing sticky bit to that program.